# JSON SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input(…) undefined

Tags: php, jquery, json

Been reading and searching for two days now and tried looking through all the other answers and questions, but I cannot figure it out. Maybe I am missing something small in my code.

I am getting `JSON SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input(…) undefined`. I know this is probably related to bad JSON somewhere, like missing a { or a ", but I cannot see it.

Here is my `JS`;

```
$("#btnUpdateInformation").on("click", function (e) {
    var formData = {
        'user_id'                     : $("#hiddenUserID").val(),
        'userPassword'                : $('#userPassword').val(),
        'userRetypePassword'          : $('#userRetypePassword').val(),
        'userBirthCountry'            : $('#userBirthCountry').val(),
        'userBirthCity'               : $('#userBirthCity').val(),
        'userBirthAddress'            : $('#userBirthAddress').val(),
        'UserZipCode'                 : $('#UserZipCode').val(),
        'userFirstName'               : $('#userFirstName').val(),
        'userLastName'                : $('#userLastName').val(),
        'userSex'                     : $('#userSex').val(),
        'userBirthDay'                : $('#userBirthDay').val(),
        'userBirthMonth'              : $('#userBirthMonth').val(),
        'userBirthYear'               : $('#userBirthYear').val(),
        'userPhoneNr'                 : $('#userPhoneNr').val(),
        'userPasswordConfirm'         : $('#userPasswordConfirm').val()
    };
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PHP/updateUserProfile.php",
    data: formData,  
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.status == 'success'){
        console.log("success");
        }else if(data.status == 'error'){
        console.log("error");
        }else if(data.status == 'no_results'){
        console.log("no results");
        }else if(data.status == 'results'){
        console.log("there are results");
        }

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data){
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data);
    }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is PHP:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once '../../PHP/class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$userPasswordConfirm = trim($_POST['userPasswordConfirm']);

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id=:user_id LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
$userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (empty($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
    $response_array['status'] = 'no_id';
    die();
}else{
    if ($userRow['userPass'] == hash('sha256', $userPasswordConfirm)){

        $user_profile = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM user_profiles WHERE user_id=:user_id LIMIT 1");
        $user_profile->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));

        if($user_profile->rowCount() > 0) {   
            $response_array['status'] = 'results';
            if($userRow['userType'] == 'admin'){ 
            //DO NOTHING ATM

            }elseif($userRow['userType'] == 'family'){

                $userPassword = trim($_POST['userPassword']);
                $userRetypePassword = trim($_POST['userRetypePassword']);
                $userBirthCountry = trim($_POST['userBirthCountry']);
                $userBirthCity = trim($_POST['userBirthCity']);
                $userBirthAddress = trim($_POST['userBirthAddress']);
                $UserZipCode = trim($_POST['UserZipCode']);
                $userFirstName = trim($_POST['userFirstName']);
                $userLastName = trim($_POST['userLastName']);
                $userSex = trim(@$_POST['userSex']);
                $userBirthDay = trim($_POST['userBirthDay']);
                $userBirthMonth = trim($_POST['userBirthMonth']);
                $userBirthYear = trim($_POST['userBirthYear']);
                $userPhoneNr = trim($_POST['userPhoneNr']);
                $userDescription = 'puudub';
                $userQuote = 'puudub';

                $date = $userBirthYear . $userBirthMonth . $userBirthDay;

                $user_profile = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE user_profiles SET aadress=:userBirthAddress, zip_code=:UserZipCode, city=:userBirthCity, country=:userBirthCountry, description=:userDescription, birthday=:date, quote=:userQuote, phone=:userPhoneNr WHERE user_id=:user_id ");
                $user_profile->bindparam(':userBirthAddress', $userBirthAddress, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $user_profile->bindparam(':UserZipCode', $UserZipCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $user_profile->bindparam(':userBirthCity', $userBirthCity, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $user_profile->bindparam(':userBirthCountry', $userBirthCountry, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $user_profile->bindparam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $user_profile->bindparam(':userDescription', $userDescription, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $user_profile->bindparam(':userQuote', $userQuote, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $user_profile->bindparam(':userPhoneNr', $userPhoneNr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $user_profile->bindparam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $user_profile->execute(); 
                return $user_profile;
                $response_array['status'] = 'success';
            }
        }else{
            $response_array['status'] = 'no_results';
            die();
        }
    }else{
        $response_array['status'] = 'error'; 
        die();
    }
echo json_encode($response_array);
}
```

EDIT

Getting this in the console.
[image]

EDIT 2

Response text from network tab:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:294
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:ai_user=80979CD0-4B9F-4C5E-9735-0CBC582B6100|2015-06-18T09:54:30.192Z; ai_session=9B999B22-3969-4929-B47D-4B4DDDEF3E80|1434621270194|1434621694875; cookieconsent_dismissed=yes; PHPSESSID=ftqs9hdu5p1cc61s8o612uvep3; _ga=GA1.1.75323905.1449732737; loggedout=1
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/Hoidja.ee/Dashboard/profile.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

EDIT 3

```
        }elseif($userRow['userType'] == 'pere'){
            $date = $userBirthYear . $userBirthMonth . $userBirthDay;

            $user_profile = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE user_profiles SET aadress=:userBirthAddress, zip_code=:UserZipCode, city=:userBirthCity, country=:userBirthCountry, description=:userDescription, birthday=:date, quote=:userQuote, phone=:userPhoneNr WHERE user_id=:user_id ");
            $user_profile->bindparam(':userBirthAddress', $userBirthAddress, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile->bindparam(':UserZipCode', $UserZipCode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile->bindparam(':userBirthCity', $userBirthCity, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile->bindparam(':userBirthCountry', $userBirthCountry, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile->bindparam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile->bindparam(':userDescription', $userDescription, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile->bindparam(':userQuote', $userQuote, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile->bindparam(':userPhoneNr', $userPhoneNr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile->bindparam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user_profile->execute();
            ///I REMOVED THIS return $user_profile;
            $response_array['status'] = 'success';
```

After I removed the return, it started working. Why is that?

Comment: Could you please add an example of the JSON output to the question.

Comment: Can we see the json ?

Comment: You can run your JSON through validators to check if they are valid http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it doesn't even show the JSON. it just displays the error in console.

Comment: You can see the JSON returned in the network tab of the console.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you kindly see the edit?

Comment: Have you tried serialize ?

Comment: Unfortunately that's just the normal console error page. We need to see the actual response text of the request.

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI while that would make the code better it wouldn't affect the format of the response which is what is causing the error.

Comment: As far as I can see you have several `die` calls before `echo json_encode($response_array);`. So you nerver retrun JSON when `die` is called.

Comment: so would the die() cause that?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how can I show it to you?

Comment: @raqulka make the request in your code, open the console, click the network tab, find the request URL and check the response text.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan kindly see the edit please.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan on line 94, I removed                 return $user_profile;
and it did not show me the error. Why is that happening?

Comment: why the down vote?

Answer (score -1):

You have several `die` calls before `echo json_encode($response_array);`.

So you never retrun JSON data when `die` is called.

Try to `json_encode` before `die`and it coul be better.

`die` is an equivalent to `exit` which terminates the script when called, so `json_encode` is never called after a `die`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

---

**EDIT**

Also, if you see your screenshot, `responseText` is empty, so it's not JSON.

The only case where you define nothing is `if($userRow['userType'] == 'admin'){`.

Correct this case to return something.

Comment: I removed all die()'s for testing and the error still persists.

Comment: I added response no_data there and still nothing.

Comment: Edited. Kindly see